# I am getting this error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 10: 10

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this [Responsive Table](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_table) in my application.
And it works in a way just like the example. I am getting my data from `Firestore` and there is no problems there. But when I have my rows per page to 10 pages and I have 11 items the error appears. So it seems that I can't set my rows per page to lower then the actual items count.

Any suggestions on where my code is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
final List<int> _perPages = [10, 20, 50, 100];
  int _total = 100;
  int? _currentPerPage = 100;
  List<bool>? _expanded;
  String? _searchKeyname = "tlname";
  String? _searchKeyid = "tlID";
  int _currentPage = 1;
  bool _isSearch = true;
  bool _isSearchid = true;

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _sourceOriginal = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _sourceFiltered = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _source = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _selecteds = [];
  // ignore: unused_field
  String _selectableKey = "id";

  String? _sortColumn;
  bool _sortAscending = true;
  bool _isLoading = true;
  final bool _showSelect = true;

  final TServices _tlServices = TlServices();
  List<TModel> _tls = <TModel>[];
  List<TModel> get tls => _tls;

  _loadFromFirebase() async {
    _tools = await _toolServices.getAllT();

  }


  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _getTData() {
    setState(() => _isLoading = true);
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> temps = [];
    var i = 0; i < _t.length;
    print(i);
    for (TModel tlData in _t) {
      temps.add({
       
        "service": tData.tlservice,
        "owner" : tData.tlowner,
        "location" : tData.tlocation,
      });
      i++;
    }
    setState(() => _isLoading = false);

    return temps;
  }


  _initializeData() async {
    _mockPullData();
    _loadFromFirebase();
  }

  _mockPullData() async {
    _expanded = List.generate(_currentPerPage!, (index) => false);

    setState(() => _isLoading = true);
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
      _sourceOriginal.clear();
      _sourceOriginal.addAll(_getTData());
      _sourceFiltered = _sourceOriginal;
      _total = _sourceFiltered.length;
      _source = _sourceFiltered.getRange(0, _t.length).toList();
      setState(() => _isLoading = false);
    });
  }

  _resetData({start = 0}) async {
    setState(() => _isLoading = true);
    num? expandedLen;
    if (_total - start < _currentPerPage!) {
      expandedLen = _total - start;
    } else {
      expandedLen = _currentPerPage;
    }
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0)).then((value) {
      _expanded = List.generate(expandedLen as int, (index) => false);
      _source.clear();
      _source = _sourceFiltered.getRange(start, start + expandedLen).toList();
      setState(() => _isLoading = false);
    });
  }
  _filterData1(value) {
    setState(() => _isLoading = true);

    try {
      if (value == "" || value == null) {
        _sourceFiltered = _sourceOriginal;
      } else {
        _sourceFiltered = _sourceOriginal
            .where((data) => data[_searchKeyid!]
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(value.toString().toLowerCase()))
            .toList();
      }

      _total = _sourceFiltered.length;
      var _rangeTop = _total < _currentPerPage! ? _total : _currentPerPage!;
      _expanded = List.generate(_rangeTop, (index) => false);
      _source = _sourceFiltered.getRange(0, _rangeTop).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    setState(() => _isLoading = false);
  }

  _filterData(value) {
    setState(() => _isLoading = true);

    try {
      if (value == "" || value == null) {
        _sourceFiltered = _sourceOriginal;
      } else {
        _sourceFiltered = _sourceOriginal
            .where((data) => data[_searchKeyname!]
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(value.toString().toLowerCase()))
            .toList();
      }

      _total = _sourceFiltered.length;
      var _rangeTop = _total < _currentPerPage! ? _total : _currentPerPage!;
      _expanded = List.generate(_rangeTop, (index) => false);
      _source = _sourceFiltered.getRange(0, _rangeTop).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    setState(() => _isLoading = false);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
```

The error refers to this Widget:

```
child: ResponsiveDatatable(
                          title: TextButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => {
                              addToolDialog(context),
                              _tnameController.text = "",
                              _tidController.text = "",


                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                            label: Text("Add"),
                          ),
                          reponseScreenSizes: [ScreenSize.xs],
                          actions: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                if (_isSearchid)
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 250,
                                    child: TextField(
                                      controller: _searchbyidController,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          hintText: 'Search here ',
                                          prefixIcon: IconButton(
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  _isSearchid = true;
                                                  _searchbyidController.text = "";
                                                });
                                                _initializeData();
                                              }),
                                          suffixIcon:  Icon(Icons.search)),
                                      onSubmitted: (value) {
                                        _filterData1(value);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                if (!_isSearchid)
                                  IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _isSearchid = true;
                                        });
                                      }),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                if (_isSearch)
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 250,
                                    child: TextField(
                                      controller: _searchbynameController,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          hintText: 'Search ',
                                          prefixIcon: IconButton(
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  _isSearch = true;
                                                  _searchbynameController.text = "";
                                                });
                                                _initializeData();
                                              }),
                                          suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                                      onSubmitted: (value) {
                                        _filterData(value);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                if (!_isSearch)
                                  IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _isSearch = true;
                                        });
                                      })
                              ],
                            )

                          ],
                          headers: _headers,
                          source: _source,
                          selecteds: _selecteds,
                          showSelect: _showSelect,
                          autoHeight: false,
                          onChangedRow: (value, header) {
                            /// print(value);
                            /// print(header);
                          },
                          onSubmittedRow: (value, header) {
                            /// print(value);
                            /// print(header);
                          },
                          onTabRow: (data) {
                            var id = data['tID'];
                            var service = data['tservice'];
                            var status = data['tstatus'];

                            updateTDialog(context, id, service, status);

                            _tnameController.text = data['name'];
                            ttypeitems = data['ttype'];
                            tgroupitems = data['tgroup'];

                          },
                          onSort: (value) {
                            setState(() => _isLoading = true);

                            setState(() {
                              _sortColumn = value;
                              _sortAscending = !_sortAscending;
                              if (_sortAscending) {
                                _sourceFiltered.sort((a, b) =>
                                    b["$_sortColumn"].compareTo(a["$_sortColumn"]));
                              } else {
                                _sourceFiltered.sort((a, b) =>
                                    a["$_sortColumn"].compareTo(b["$_sortColumn"]));
                              }
                              var _rangeTop = _currentPerPage! < _sourceFiltered.length
                                  ? _currentPerPage!
                                  : _sourceFiltered.length;
                              _source = _sourceFiltered.getRange(0, _rangeTop).toList();
                              _searchKeyname = value;

                              _isLoading = false;
                            });
                          },
                          expanded: _expanded,
                          sortAscending: _sortAscending,
                          sortColumn: _sortColumn,
                          isLoading: _isLoading,
                          onSelect: (value, item) {
                            print("$value  $item ");
                            if (value!) {
                              setState(() => _selecteds.add(item));
                            } else {
                              setState(
                                      () => _selecteds.removeAt(_selecteds.indexOf(item)));
                            }
                          },
                          onSelectAll: (value) {
                            if (value!) {
                              setState(() => _selecteds =
                                  _source.map((entry) => entry).toList().cast());
                            } else {
                              setState(() => _selecteds.clear());
                            }
                          },
                          footers: [
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                              child: Text("Rader per side:"),
                            ),
                            if (_perPages.isNotEmpty)
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                                child: DropdownButton<int>(
                                  value: _currentPerPage,
                                  items: _perPages
                                      .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                                    child: Text("$e"),
                                    value: e,
                                  ))
                                      .toList(),
                                  onChanged: (dynamic value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _currentPerPage = value;
                                      _currentPage = 1;
                                      _resetData();
                                    });
                                  },
                                  isExpanded: false,
                                ),
                              ),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                              child:
                              Text("$_currentPage - $_currentPerPage av $_total"),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                                size: 16,
                              ),
                              onPressed: _currentPage == 1
                                  ? null
                                  : () {
                                var _nextSet = _currentPage - _currentPerPage!;
                                setState(() {
                                  _currentPage = _nextSet > 1 ? _nextSet : 1;
                                  _resetData(start: _currentPage - 1);
                                });
                              },
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 16),
                              onPressed: _currentPage + _currentPerPage! - 1 > _total
                                  ? null
                                  : () {
                                var _nextSet = _currentPage + _currentPerPage!;

                                setState(() {
                                  _currentPage = _nextSet < _total
                                      ? _nextSet
                                      : _total - _currentPerPage!;
                                  _resetData(start: _nextSet - 1);
                                });
                              },
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                            )
                          ],
                          headerDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.blueGrey,
                              border: Border(
                                  bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1))),
                          selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border(
                                bottom:
                                BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1)),
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          headerTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          rowTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
```

Comment: Please provide the exact line where you get the error.

Comment: Here is the full error: `The following IndexError was thrown building ResponsiveDatatable(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _ResponsiveDatatableState#d01a5):
RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 10: 10

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ResponsiveDatatable ResponsiveDatatable:file:///D:te/t/lib/pages/page.dart:346:32`. I will update the question with the code the error refers to.

Comment: @activout.se , nothing you can think of that is wrong with the code?

Comment: Sorry, you need to make a shorter reproducible example if I'm going to investigate further

Comment: Hi, I will try to make a shorter code.